# Download huggingface table / DataFrame?

Tags: dataframe, huggingface, gradio, huggingface-hub

I was looking at:

https://huggingface.co/spaces/HuggingFaceH4/open_llm_leaderboard

[image]

It's a valuable data table and I wanted to download it in a machine readable format. There is no static file that is rendered out of [the repo](https://huggingface.co/spaces/HuggingFaceH4/open_llm_leaderboard/tree/main), but [app.py](https://huggingface.co/spaces/HuggingFaceH4/open_llm_leaderboard/blob/main/app.py) is executed (as per [README metadata](https://huggingface.co/spaces/HuggingFaceH4/open_llm_leaderboard/blob/main/README.md)) - which creates a [leaderboard DataFrame](https://huggingface.co/spaces/HuggingFaceH4/open_llm_leaderboard/blob/main/app.py#L112) out of a separate [evaluation repo](https://huggingface.co/spaces/HuggingFaceH4/lmeh_evaluations) which seems to be private.

How can one access that DataFrame from the outside?

---

Edit: I tried the the linked docker command fails (somewhat expectedly):

```bash
$ docker run -it -p 7860:7860 \
    --platform=linux/amd64 \
    -e H4_TOKEN=hf_nottherealtokenweorpqweruuoid \
    -e IS_PUBLIC=true \
    registry.hf.space/huggingfaceh4-open-llm-leaderboard:latest \
    python app.py

...

Cloning into '.'...
remote: Repository not found
fatal: repository 'https://huggingface.co/datasets/HuggingFaceH4/lmeh_evaluations/' not found
Error(s) during clone:
git clone failed: exit status 128
```

Cf. https://huggingface.co/spaces/HuggingFaceH4/open_llm_leaderboard/discussions/50

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Open LLM leaderboard dataset has been made public as a dataset [here](https://huggingface.co/datasets/open-llm-leaderboard/results), and can be manipulated using the `datasets` library or downloaded using `git`.

Have fun with the data!

(Disclaimer: I'm one of the leaderboard's programmers/researchers.)

Comment: import datasets

Comment: I tried to load the data using python, but it gives error

import datasets
aa=datasets.load_dataset('open-llm-leaderboard/results')

TypeError: Couldn't cast array of type
struct<model_name: string, model_sha: string, model_dtype: string, lighteval_sha: string, num_few_shot_default: int64, num_fewshot_seeds: int64, override_batch_size: int64, max_samples: null>
to
{'model_name': Value(dtype='string', id=None), 'model_sha': Value(dtype='string', ...

Comment: Hi @LevSelector, it's an issue we're aware of, some files changed shape through the history of the leaderboard - we'd advise you git clone the dataset instead for now.

Comment: Clef, thank you.
`   
    https://huggingface.co/datasets/open-llm-leaderboard/results
    git lfs install
    git clone https://huggingface.co/datasets/open-llm-leaderboard/results
`   

I now have a results directory with many subdirectories and json files.
But how I convert it into something as a leaderboard CSV file ? or Pandas dataframe?

Comment: Hi @LevSelector, please look at the code we use in the leaderboard space to convert the files.